# Use SCOM SDK with tls1.2

Tags: sdk, tls1.2, scom, system-center

How do we set the tls version in the scom sdk? I use

```
ManagementGroup.Connect
```

with ManagementGroupConnectionSettings but it does not have any parameter to specify the tls version.

SCOM 2012 R2 onwards, TLS1.2 is supported. The same should be supported in the sdk as well to create a secured connection with tls1.2 from a client application.

Searched the microsoft document but did not get any information. Could anybody please shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once the infrastructure of your 2012 R2 is updated to above UR14 and a client configured for only TLS 1.2 should be able to connect using the updated UR14 and above SDK files. (I am not sure which of the SDK files has the specific TLS 1.2 update). Kevin Holman has a write up on how to update your infrastructure to support TLS 1.2 https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kevinholman/2018/05/06/implementing-tls-1-2-enforcement-with-scom/
It would be best to review the blog post above get your infrastructure up to or above UR14, and then implement the changed necessary to support TLS 1.2. Once the infrastructure is configured to use only TLS 1.2 and SCOM is configured for TLS 1.2 SCOM communication should be utilizing TLS 1.2 moving forward. Hope this helps!

The Microsoft documentation for TLS 1.2 and SCOM is available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/plan-security-tls12-config?view=sc-om-2016
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051111/tls-1-2-protocol-support-deployment-guide-for-system-center-2016

Comment: thanks for the response. I have made the changes in SCOM server 2012 r2 already, but wanted to know if from the client connector side any changes are needed in specifying the protocol like i mentioned in the question.

Comment: The answer to your question would be yes that the client would need to be configured to use TLS 1.2; along with the SCOM infrastructure.

Comment: configuration in OS level ? the registry that we do ? or something in the API parameter ? as far as i checked, API mentioned in question doesn't have any parameter to specify the tls protocol. So i assume its the OS level configuration for stricly using TLS1.2 that you are referring, in the client connector application side.

Comment: Yes it is configuring the OS of the client to use only TLS 1.2; again this is an OS level configuration change.